# how create XSD for XML with random elements and fixed attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

This is the snippet of XML file, `<_0>`, `<_7>`... `<_100>` are random, `<id>`, `<contact_id/>`, `<status>` and `<is_test_data>` are fixed. I need to create a XSD file to validate this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <result_ok>1</result_ok>
    <total_count>6</total_count>
    <page>1</page>
    <total_pages>1</total_pages>
    <results_per_page>50</results_per_page>
    <data>
        <_0>
            <id>12</id>
            <contact_id/>
            <status>Complete</status>
            <is_test_data>1</is_test_data>
        </_0>
        <_7>
            <id>13</id>
            <contact_id/>
            <status>Complete</status>
            <is_test_data>1</is_test_data>
        </_7>
        <_2>
            <id>14</id>
            <contact_id/>
            <status>Complete</status>
            <is_test_data>1</is_test_data>
        </_2>
        <_6>
            <id>15</id>
            <contact_id/>
            <status>Complete</status>
            <is_test_data>1</is_test_data>
        </_6>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <_100>
            <id>15</id>
            <contact_id/>
            <status>Complete</status>
            <is_test_data>1</is_test_data>
        </_100>
    </data>
</result>
```

This is the XSD i created, but not sure how to create schema for random elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="apiresult">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="result_ok" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="total_count" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="page" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="total_pages" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="results_per_page" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="data">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="_0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" />
                                        <xs:element name="contact_id" />
                                        <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="is_test_data" type="xs:int" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: It would be very easy to do this with XSD if you are able to change `<_0>` `<_n>` for `<randomElement value="_0">` and `<randomElement value="_n>`. This way you fix the name and only have a random attribute value. If you can't do something like this you would have to use many assertions which would be a lot more complex and less expressive.

Comment: thanks sergio, how do i use the random element in my XSD. i know for sure all elements are ("_" + a numeric value). In most cases the elements will be in order, e.g. <_0>, <_1>, <_2>...

Comment: You do it by removing the XSD content model of the element and adding as many XPath assertions as you need to specify and check that the content is as you expect it to be. This is quite long and the hard way, you can see examples of xpath and assertions in other questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with XSD. (Except if you essentially do the whole validation using XSD 1.1 assertions, but that's not really using XSD at all).

If you want to validate this bizarre XML, I would suggest first transforming it into something more mainstream, e.g. changing all the element names using XSLT.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, XSD, XSLT is all new to me. Can you please provide me with a sample

Comment: Sorry, I don't write code for people. I just try to point them in the right direction. In any case, if you want to learn a new language, starting with a sample that you don't understand is not the best approach: you need to do some reading.

Comment: thanks for you comment, i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692889/modify-part-of-xml-element-name-and-replace-with-increment-number